# Android Java listener for variable on Spring Boot server change

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, heroku, architecture

Hello I am wondering if this is possible to notify Android with some kind of listener the best via Retrofit when variable on server side change (to be specific concrete record on database shows up)?

Or you have any other ideas how can I achieve that with the simplest way.

The use case is that: I am developing Android RPG game. There are players that can fight with each other. They are all located on world map and you can choose the player you want to fight with. And now I want to get information in code once I am attacked or inform another player that he is attacked and open a new arena map dedicated for PvP fighting.

Currently I do it by retrofit call to server that checks if that record in database exists every few seconds but I guess it is not the best solution, as some people can have various internet limitations.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [web sockets](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/). They behave as you need.

Comment: In this example I need to know javascript? What if I want the client to be Android device not browser and javascript?

Comment: @Kiubaz no, you don't need to know JavaScript. On Android you can use [Socket.io](https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/installation.html) library.

Comment: Thanks for feedback but before that I got familiar with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messages) sending from backend to device. Is it good option too for my use case?

Comment: @Kiubaz I'm not familliar with game development, but FCM is designed for different purpose (mostly notifications to user when app is not running). In my opinion, you should use sockets.